# I cannot connect my web server via public IP in AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm studying AWS.

But I have a problem that I cannot connect to my web server on my AWS instance

AWS instance is Windows Server 2012

[this is my instance status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxYaZ.png)

I want to connect my web server via public ip 52.78.47.142 outside the AWS instance

if I connect to the private ip 172.31.15.206 inside the instance, home page showed up.

But if I connect to the public ip 52.78.47.142 inside the AWS instance and outside the AWS instance, home page didn't show up both.

although I set a new rule for http protocol at port 80, it doens't work

any helps? thanks a lot...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS EC2 security groups don't seem to apply for Public IPs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154453/aws-ec2-security-groups-dont-seem-to-apply-for-public-ips)

Comment: @KarenB No, i have just one instance, i just want to connect my instance to public ip via internet

Comment: You still have to add the public IP to the instance's security group.

Answer (score 2):

open up **tcp:80** port in the security group(Inbound) for the IP address of the machine from where your accessing the website( In this case your **Desktop or Laptop IP address**).

If you are trying to access the web server from another AWS Instance open the port for that particular Instance IP. For troubleshooting case you can open up All traffic and test it(Though this is **not recommended**)